# Difference between including module in single line vs multi line

Tags: ruby

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule1
  include MyModule2
  include MyModule3
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule1, MyModule2, MyModule3
end
```

All the modules have a common method `test`. When accessing in multiline, it calls `test` method from the last module included, but in case of single line `include`, it calls the method from the first module included. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: one reason may be, Don't Repeat Youself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-include):

> Invokes `Module.append_features` on each parameter in **reverse** order.